local rpm installation dependencies issue
I am trying to install a few rpms on a test server without internet connection.
I have downloaded the rpm files based "yum deplist " from other  server which has internet connections and has the rpm installed.
Then I copied all rpm files to the test linux server.
[root@localhost Downloads]# dnf localinstall glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides glibc-common = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 needed by glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides glibc-langpack = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 needed by glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64 from @commandline
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@localhost Downloads]# dnf localinstall glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides glibc = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 needed by glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64 from @commandline
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

so I install glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2, it asks for glibc-common = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2, when I install glibc-common = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2, it asks for 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2:
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -i glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8d8b756f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc-common = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 is needed by glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64
        glibc-langpack = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 is needed by glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -i glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8d8b756f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc = 2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]# dnf localinstall *.rpm --disablerepo=*
No repository match: *
Package audit-3.1.2-2.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Package basesystem-11-13.el9.noarch is already installed.
Package bash-5.1.8-9.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Package libgcc-11.4.1-3.0.1.el9.i686 is already installed.
Package libmnl-1.0.4-15.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Package libnfnetlink-1.0.1-21.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Package pcre-8.44-3.el9.3.x86_64 is already installed.
Package policycoreutils-3.6-2.1.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Error:
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides selinux-policy-any = 38.1.35-2.0.3.el9_4.2 needed by selinux-policy-38.1.35-2.0.3.el9_4.2.noarch from @commandline
 Problem 2: cannot install both glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64 from @commandline and glibc-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64 from @System
  - package glibc-gconv-extra-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64 from @System requires glibc(x86-64) = 2.34-100.0.1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package glibc-gconv-extra-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64
 Problem 3: cannot install both glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9_4.2.x86_64 from @commandline and glibc-common-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64 from @System
  - package glibc-langpack-en-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64 from @System requires glibc-common = 2.34-100.0.1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package glibc-langpack-en-2.34-100.0.1.el9.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Any ideas on how to resolve it?

dnf localinstall glibc: let's not do that. That is virtually guaranteed to break things. (as you can see). Tell us what you want to do, and we might be able to tell you how it's done correctly; but updating the libc alone won't work out. This is not how you do offline installations on RHEL (and RHEL-alike) machines.

I managed to resolve the issue by using rpm -i [rpm file[s]]

thanks @MarcusMüller

that even more looks like an extremely bad idea; just because a lower-level program didn't stop you from doing this doesn't mean things will work. Good luck!
